# Defining field and its data type as a MAP in application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is it possible to define datatype for fields in application.yaml in spring boot?

Eg:

```
ingestiondata:
  NAME: String
  WEIGHT: Double
  DOB: Date
```

Basically I want to externalize the data type identification.

I receive a map in the below format

```
MAP<Integer,Map<String,String>> data = Map.of(1,Map.of("Name","GVR","WEIGHT","130.0","DOB","01/01/1992"),
2, Map.of("Name","RRR","WEIGHT","10","DOB","10/13/2020"))
```

I want to parse the values to the corresponding data type so that I can perform operations like

weight > weight+2 etc on Integers
and so on

I have around 50 fields which can fall into one of the wrapper types or date or String

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

we don't explicitly define data type in .yaml file

```
name="name"//string type
age=age//integer type
```

you can use in your class

```
public class ConfigProperties {
String name;
int age;
...
}
```

for more details you can follow this https://www.javatpoint.com/yaml-data-types

Comment: I have used this way of yaml declaration before. I wanted to understand if we can define the metadata of the field I am going to receive for further processing in the code ..